# opening existing blog post using microsoft word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-office-2007, blogging

Whenever I open "existing blog posts" using Microsoft Office 2007, I am presented with last 25 posts. How to open the old posts using MS office?

Comment: How are you using Word to open blog posts?  I thought blogs were online...?

Comment: Office button --> Publish --> Blog, then under "Blog post",  click "open existing". You gotta set up the credentials of blog accounts, though.